# django models request get id error Room matching query does not exist

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-queryset, models

i have two models, when i do request.POST.get('room_id') or ('id') i'm getting an error Room matching query does not exist.
how to solved this problem? help me

```
    class Room(models.Model):
        status = models.BooleanField('Status',default=True)
        name = models.CharField('Name', max_length=100, unique=True)

    class Book(models.Model):
        date = models.DateTimeField('Created',auto_now_add=True)
        from_date = models.DateField('Check-in')
        to_date = models.DateField('Check-out')
        room = models.ForeignKey(Room, related_name='booking')
```

i need detail room request get id, booked dates range(from_date,to_date)

```
def room_detail(request,pk):
    room = get_object_or_404(Room,pk=pk)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = BookForm(request.POST,room=room)
        if form.is_valid():
            s = form.save(commit=True)          
            s.save()
            return redirect(request.path)
    else:
        form = BookForm()

    #roomid = Room.objects.values('id')
    type = request.POST.get('id') # or get('room_id')
    rooms = Room.objects.get(id=type)

    start_dates = rooms.booking.values_list('from_date',flat=True)
    end_dates = rooms.booking.values_list('to_date',flat=True)
    dates = [start + timedelta(days=i) for start, end in zip(start_dates,end_dates) for i in range((end-start).days+1)]

    c = {}
    c['form'] = form
    return render_to_response('rooms_detail.html',c)
```

please help me, thanks in advance

Comment: Do you have the exact error message and line?

Comment: why is your type = req...and so on not in your POST method?

Comment: @317070 thanks for the quick reaply, i get an error app.models.DoesNotExist: Room matching query does not exist. how to change it?

Comment: @RogerFederer how to do it? can view example please

Answer (score 5):

Move your lines

```
#roomid = Room.objects.values('id')
type = request.POST.get('id') # or get('room_id')
rooms = Room.objects.get(id=type)
```

inside the post method.

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = BookForm(request.POST,room=room)
    if form.is_valid():
        #roomid = Room.objects.values('id')
        type = request.POST.get('id') # or get('room_id')
        rooms = Room.objects.get(id=type)
        s = form.save(commit=True)          
        s.save()
        return redirect(request.path)
```

Answer (score 3):

You are looking into request.POST, even if the request.method is not equal to 'POST'. This will not work, because when the request is not an HTTP-post, the POST-member of your request is empty.

Comment: For things like this you could just leave a comment.

Answer (score 0):

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = BookForm(request.POST,room=room)
    if form.is_valid():
        type = request.POST.get('id')
        rooms = Room.objects.get(id=type)
        object = form.save(commit=True)          
        object.save()
        return redirect(request.path)
```